# Geogebra - constructing the smallest circle that contains a triangle

Tags: geometry, math-software

I want to create a Geogebra demonstration of the smallest enclosing circle of a given triangle.

The Geogebra tutorial shows how to create the circumcircle of a triangle (by calculating the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors), but, the circumcircle might be very large, there may be a much smaller enclosing circle.

A possible solution is to select the largest side of the triangle, say AB, and construct a circle that has AB as a diameter. But, I don't know how to tell Geogebra to select the largest side.

Is there another way?

Comment: [this article](http://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/circumscribed-circle-vs-minimum-enclosing-circle-i/) might help.

Comment: [another article](http://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/circumscribed-circle-vs-minimal-enclosing-circle-ii/) from same blog.

Comment: [part 3](http://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/circumscribed-circle-vs-minimum-enclosing-circle-iii/)

Comment: Part 3 contains the following theorem: " If \triangle ABC is acute or right, then the circumscribed circle is the smallest enclosing circle. If \triangle ABC is obtuse, then the circumscribed circle is strictly larger than the smallest enclosing circle. Moreover, the smallest enclosing circle is centered at the midpoint of the longest side with radius half the length of this side."

But this still doesn't help in constructing this in Geogebra

Comment: No. It doesn't. You can be sure that the circumscribed method works by checking none of the angles are greater than $90$. If they *are* greater, than your method should work. You have the co-ordinates of the points right? Is there a distance function in GeoGebra? And anything similar to an if-else construct? I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is in GeoGebra:
https://www.geogebra.org/m/mWnvve4s

You can download the .ggb file to see how it was made. The tricky bits are these to select the correct center and edge points:

> If[α  <  90°, If[β  <  90°, If[γ  <  90°, O, D], E], F]
>
> If[α  <  90°, B, A]

Here's a similar construction for a square:
https://www.geogebra.org/m/mkyEZsFF