# A circle can include all but one of n points, but which one can it be?

Tags: circles, geometric-construction, combinatorial-geometry, plane-geometry

The answers to the question "[Circle enclosing all but one of n points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659849/72968)" demonstrate that, given $n$ points, it is possible to construct a circle such that all but one of the points is inside the circle (i.e. given a set of points $A_i$, $i=1, 2, \dots, n$, we can find some point $B$ — not necessarily, though possibly, in our set $\{A_i\}$ — and a radius $r$ such that the distance $A_iB < r$ for $n-1$ of the points, while the other point has $A_iB > r$).

Obviously the solution is not unique: there are generally many such ways the circle could be drawn, including by leaving different points outside the circle. But given a set of points $\{A_i\}$, is there a way to identify (preferably by geometric construction rather than a co-ordinate geometry calculation) that subset of points which *could* be the "odd one out" when a circle enclosing $n-1$ points is drawn?

For example, given any three non-collinear points it seems clear that for *any* of those points, we could construct a circle that leaves that point alone out. If the three points lie in a line, then it isn't possible to draw a circle that only leaves the middle point out (because circles are convex, and for a convex set then any point on the line segment between two points inside the set must also be inside the set), whereas leaving out either end point is easy. Given four points arranged in a square, it is straightforward to construct circles to leave out any given point; if instead the four points were arranged so that three were the vertices of an equilateral triangle while the fourth is at its centroid, it seems the central point can't be left out but the others can.

My intuition is that *any point that does not lie in the convex hull of the set of other points* is "leave-outable" because we can then draw a line separating it from the other points, and by using a large enough radius we can construct a circle with a centre on the "$n-1$ points" side of the line, and whose circumference is "close enough" to the relevant segment of this line (sufficiently "approximately straight") for our point to be on the extreme side of the arc just as it was to the line, while making sure the circle is big enough to enclose the desired $n-1$ points. My intuition also suggests that *any point that lies in the convex hull of the set of other points* is "not leave-outable" for similar reasons to the three collinear points example ... if both these intuitions are correct, a necessary and sufficient condition is "points that don't lie in the convex hull of the other points". Is this intuition correct, and if so, is there a nice proof and/or construction for it?

Comment: The second hypothesis follows from the fact that a disk covering $n-1$ points is a superset of their convex hull.

Comment: @Rahul Nicely put, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $n$ points, we can draw a circle around $n-1$ of them provided the remaining point does not lie in the convex hull of the others. The answers to the question [Circle enclosing all but one of $n$ points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659849/72968) show that at least one such "leave-outable" point must exist. The condition that the point does not lie in the convex hull of the others tells us which points can be left out. For example in the diagram below, (a) $P_6$ can be left out, even though (b) it lies inside the [minimum covering circle of the remaining points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem), because (c) we can draw a larger circle with a centre further away. On the other hand, $P_3$ and $P_4$ lie inside the convex hull of the other points  so cannot be left out: this convex hull must be a subset of any disc that contains the other points, and so $P_4$ and $P_5$ must lie inside the disc and cannot be left out.

[image: Which points can be left out?]

More generally, we can draw a circle around $n-k$ of the points if (but not "only if") the convex hull of the omitted $k$ points does not intersect with the convex hull of the $n-k$ points we wish to encircle. The case $k=1$ is just a special case where we use the fact the convex hull of the omitted point is just the point itself (this is a convex set!), and in this case the fact the point does not lie in the convex hull of the encircled points shows that the two convex hulls *must* be disjoint.

By the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), if the two convex sets are disjoint then we can draw a separating line between them. By drawing a circle with large enough radius and centre far enough away, we can make the circumference of our circle "approximate" this separating line if necessary, so that we can include one convex hull inside our circle without crossing over into the other.

[image: Circles around disjoint convex hulls]